# Scraping coronavirus-related data from a page which is dynamically loaded from a Tableau canvas (I think...)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I will be more than happy to find out this question is a duplicate, but if so - I can't find that Q&A.

There is this mysterious page from the [New York State Department of Health](https://covid19tracker.health.ny.gov/views/NYS-COVID19-Tracker/NYSDOHCOVID-19Tracker-Fatalities?%3Aembed=yes&%3Atoolbar=no&%3Atabs=n) containing "Fatalities by County and Age Group". As the title implies, it contains two tables ("By County"/"By Age Group").

For some strange reason, the data on this page is super-secured. It can't be selected, the page can't be saved and it can't be printed. The data isn't on the page source. I also tried (and failed) to inspect xhr calls for the data.

Obviously, requests and beautifulsoup can't handle it. I tried the usual Selenium incantations (so, unless I'm told otherwise, I won't clutter this question with "what I tried" snippets).

Desire output: the data from those two tables, in any conceivable format.

The only thing I can think of is to take a screenshot and try to ocr the image...

I don't know if it's Selenium, Tableau, the NYS Dep't of Health or just me, but it's time to call in the heavy artillery...

Comment: Try [this](https://filebin.net/mz3mtd7e8cejqkrx) to send a post http requests in order to fetch json content.

Comment: @asmitu that comment is out of knowledge at all. Jack is not new for scraping field. ! if you can call it. do it better than redirecting to other resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain for you the scenario:

1. Website is generating a `session` id behind that parameter `X-Session-Id` which is dynamically generated once you visit the [main page](https://covid19tracker.health.ny.gov/) page index. So i called it via `GET` request and I've picked it up from the `headers` response.
2. I've figured out an `POST` request which is automatically generated before you hit your desired `url` which is actually using the `session` id which we collected before. here is it `https://covid19tracker.health.ny.gov/vizql/w/NYS-COVID19-Tracker/v/NYSDOHCOVID-19Tracker-Fatalities/clear/sessions/{session id}`
3. Now we can call your target which is `https://covid19tracker.health.ny.gov/views/NYS-COVID19-Tracker/NYSDOHCOVID-19Tracker-Fatalities?%3Aembed=yes&%3Atoolbar=no&%3Atabs=n`.
4. Now I noticed another `XHR` request to the `back-end` `API`. But before we do the call, We will parse the `HTML` content for picking up the `time` object which is responsible on generating the data `freshly` from the `API` so we will get an instant data (consider it like a live chat actually). in our case it's behind `lastUpdatedAt` inside the `HTML`
5. I noticed as well that we will need to pickup the recent `X-Session-Id` generated from our previous `POST` request.
6. Now we will make the call using our picked up `session` to `https://covid19tracker.health.ny.gov/vizql/w/NYS-COVID19-Tracker/v/NYSDOHCOVID-19Tracker-Fatalities/bootstrapSession/sessions/{session}`

Now we have received the full response. you can parse it or do whatever you want.

```py
import requests
import re


data = {
    'worksheetPortSize': '{"w":1536,"h":1250}',
    'dashboardPortSize': '{"w":1536,"h":1250}',
    'clientDimension': '{"w":1536,"h":349}',
    'renderMapsClientSide': 'true',
    'isBrowserRendering': 'true',
    'browserRenderingThreshold': '100',
    'formatDataValueLocally': 'false',
    'clientNum': '',
    'navType': 'Reload',
    'navSrc': 'Top',
    'devicePixelRatio': '2.5',
    'clientRenderPixelLimit': '25000000',
    'allowAutogenWorksheetPhoneLayouts': 'true',
    'sheet_id': 'NYSDOH%20COVID-19%20Tracker%20-%20Fatalities',
    'showParams': '{"checkpoint":false,"refresh":false,"refreshUnmodified":false}',
    'filterTileSize': '200',
    'locale': 'en_US',
    'language': 'en',
    'verboseMode': 'false',
    ':session_feature_flags': '{}',
    'keychain_version': '1'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.post(url)
        sid = r.headers.get("X-Session-Id")

        r = req.post(
            f"https://covid19tracker.health.ny.gov/vizql/w/NYS-COVID19-Tracker/v/NYSDOHCOVID-19Tracker-Fatalities/clear/sessions/{sid}")

        r = req.get(
            "https://covid19tracker.health.ny.gov/views/NYS-COVID19-Tracker/NYSDOHCOVID-19Tracker-Fatalities?%3Aembed=yes&%3Atoolbar=no&%3Atabs=n")

        match = re.search(r"lastUpdatedAt.+?(\d+),", r.text).group(1)

        time = '{"featureFlags":"{\"MetricsAuthoringBeta\":false}","isAuthoring":false,"isOfflineMode":false,"lastUpdatedAt":xxx,"workbookId":9}'.replace(
            'xxx', f"{match}")

        data['stickySessionKey'] = time
        nid = r.headers.get("X-Session-Id")

        r = req.post(
            f"https://covid19tracker.health.ny.gov/vizql/w/NYS-COVID19-Tracker/v/NYSDOHCOVID-19Tracker-Fatalities/bootstrapSession/sessions/{nid}", data=data)

        print(r.text)


main("https://covid19tracker.health.ny.gov")
```

Comment: I have no idea how you figured all this out - my hat off to you! Thanks - and I learned something new, too.

Comment: @JackFleeting you welcome :P Just by calling the web daily. also I've been working with many `.gov` website before :) .

Comment: @JackFleeting [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60906977/unable-to-let-my-script-populate-result-using-post-requests)

Comment: wow this is amazing, thank you ahmed! @JackFleeting have you figured out how to parse the results from this? I am trying to get similar data and cannot quite figure out how the data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a [tableau scraper library](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping) to extract the data from Tableau worksheets

You can get all data in pandas dataframe for each worksheet with the following code:

```py
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS

url = "https://covid19tracker.health.ny.gov/views/NYS-COVID19-Tracker/NYSDOHCOVID-19Tracker-Fatalities"

ts = TS()
ts.loads(url)
dashboard = ts.getWorkbook()

for t in dashboard.worksheets:
    # show worksheet name
    print(f"WORKSHEET NAME : {t.name}")
    # show dataframe for this worksheet
    print(t.data)
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://replit.com/@bertrandmartel/TableauCovidNY)