# How to get POST url specification from a tableau-related web call

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, tableau-api, screen-scraping

This relates to a previously asked and anwered question: [Scraping coronavirus-related data from a page which is dynamically loaded from a Tableau canvas (I think...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61062341/scraping-coronavirus-related-data-from-a-page-which-is-dynamically-loaded-from-a/61065474#61065474)

Here is a component of the answer that I am having difficulty with: "I've figured out an POST request which is automatically generated before you hit your desired url which is actually using the session id which we collected before. here is it [https://covid19tracker.health.ny.gov/vizql/w/NYS-COVID19-Tracker/v/NYSDOHCOVID-19Tracker-Fatalities/clear/sessions/{session](https://covid19tracker.health.ny.gov/vizql/w/NYS-COVID19-Tracker/v/NYSDOHCOVID-19Tracker-Fatalities/clear/sessions/%7Bsession) id}"

My question: How do I determine the format of the POST request url? I have looked through the javascript in the html page and cannot figure out how the url gets composed.

Thanks.

Comment: use chrome development console, go to network tab

Comment: Answered. Thank you very much for your help with this.